# Save recieved push notifications in sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, sqflite

I have been assigned to save received push notifications both foreground and background in sqflite. I'm able to save foreground notifications generated from the flutter_local_notification package but unable to save notifications received from firebase_messaging both in foreground and background.
Please guide me to solve this issue.

Edit-
I have resolved this issue by adding `SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));` above FirebaseMessagingPlugin. below is the full code

Application.kt

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {

        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging")) {
            SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications")) {
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
        }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant



class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    }
}
```

then Register Application.kt in Manifest File

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `data` in your messages. To be interpreted in the background and foreground. At the end of your `onMessage` settings, before the semicolon, at `.onData({write your logic here});`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) await Firebase.initializeApp();


  print('Got a message whilst in the BACKGROUND or TERMINATED!');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print(
        'Message also contained a notification, with the following:\nTitle: ${message.notification?.title}\nBody: ${message.notification?.body}');
  }
}

handleNotifications() async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings status = await messaging.getNotificationSettings();
  if (!(status.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) ||
      status.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true, announcement: false, badge: true, carPlay: false, provisional: true, sound: true);
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('user granted permissions');
    }
  }

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(badge: true, alert: true, sound: true);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
    print(' Got a message whilst in the FOREGROUND! ');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print(
          'Message also contained a notification, with the following:\nTitle: ${message.notification?.title}\nBody: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }

    return;
  }).onData((data) {
    //do your sqflite or any other logic here
    print('data from stream: ${data.data}');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) async {
    print('NOTIFICATION MESSAGE TAPPED');
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print(
          'Message also contained a notification, with the following:\nTitle: ${message.notification?.title}\nBody: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }

    return;
  }).onData((data) {
    //do your sqflite or any other logic here
    print('data from stream: ${data.data}');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  return;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  handleNotifications();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I added a complete example of working code, check it out. Put them as they are, above `Main` then `void main()`

Comment: i am using  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3. i have placed above code as you said but its showing red lines at some parts of code. I think you maybe using different version of  firebase_messaging

Comment: This is using version 9.0. if you have red lines, use your current setup, and implement the `onData` function, that was the idea of posting the code. I commented them with`sqflite logic`.

Comment: When i type 'FirebaseMessaging.' the only method available is 'private' after dot. I can't see other methods like how there is 'FirebaseMessaging.onMessage' in above code. After creating object i can able to access .configure method as like in this link [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-flutter-app/) . Now I able to save foreground messages but its not saving message received in background.